# Mind mapping software

Tags: windows, diagram, mind-mapping

I need a free of charge software to create simple mind maps. Something free, fast, reliable, simple.

I have tried a lot, and I like these two:

- [Scapple](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/scapple). - It's not free (I used it as trial), and there are very few features. However, I like its speed, simplicity, reliability.
- [Vue](https://vue.tufts.edu/). - it's free, and there are more features. However, the kerning is horrible, and undo/redo is buggy (the size and placement of the blocks will be changed to somewhat arbitrary). Also, it starts not very quickly (it's Java).

Some things I like about them:

- Each block can have as many connections as you want. (It's not limited to 4 or 8.).
- The blocks are supporting word wrapping.
- You can have text on your connections (e.g. yes/no). Vue only.

(Both of them works on all three main systems: Windows, macOS, and Linux. However, I'm a Windows user currently.)

What tools would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best FOSS Mind Mapping tools I know of are [VYM](http://www.insilmaril.de/vym/#mc:0,bo:3,bo:6) and [Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).
Both are excelent.

I personally prefer VYM, but if you're not a Linuxer it has the drawback of not having a recent Win/Mac compilation.

Freemind has versions for all major OSs.

**Edit**

As for the argument that these softwares doesn't have word wrapping and the connections are limited... nothing farther from truth. These are 2 of the most complete and full featured softwares in the market. They don't have only word-wrapping. They have a complete support for text and attachments, among MANY other features. And the number of connections is limited by your machine's memory. There's no pratical limit.

Have you even installed them ?

Here some examples of what Freemind can do (flash needed):

http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/extensions/freemind/flashwindow.php?initLoadFile=/wiki/images/a/a5/Pub_Sub.mm&startCollapsedToLevel=5&mm_title=Pub_Sub.mm

http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/extensions/freemind/flashwindow.php?startCollapsedToLevel=4&initLoadFile=/wiki/images/1/1a/Python_WebLinks.mm&mm_title=Python%202.5%20Computer%20Language%20-%20Contents

http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/extensions/freemind/flashwindow.php?initLoadFile=/wiki/images/7/7f/CProgramming.mm&startCollapsedToLevel=5&mm_title=C%20Programming

Here's an example with word-wrapping:

http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/extensions/freemind/flashwindow.php?initLoadFile=/wiki/images/e/eb/Anonymity_on_the_Edge2.mm&startCollapsedToLevel=5&mm_title=Anonymity%20on%20the%20Edge2.mm

In case you don't have flash, here's the image of this last example:

[image: Word-wrapping mindmap example]

**Also please note that the example you commented it's not a mind map.** Here's a guide on how to create mind maps:

https://blog.iqmatrix.com/how-to-mind-map

Comment: Thanks, but no, they are definitely not something what I'm searching for.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain why?

Comment: Please update your question to say why they are no good for you

Comment: As I understand, they dont' have [word wrapping](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/assets/image/scapple/scapple-map.jpg), and also the number of connections between blocks is limited to 4 or 8 (you can't have e.g. 20 connections from the single block).

Comment: please see my edit